# How to get index of Class item in array with Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

I have class as shown below:

```
struct Cur: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    let switchVal:Bool
}
```

This class populates an array and the array is being displayed in UITableView. How to detect which switch button (switchVal) is toggled, therefore how to get "id" of the related element.

I am detecting when UISwitchButton is toggled inside a prototype cell like this:

```
@IBAction func switchBtn(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     if sender.isOn {

     }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals in your properties

Comment: btw defining your switchVal a constant false makes no sense

Comment: And isOn is a non optional Bool. Using `== true` is redundant. To check if not isOn just use `if !sender.isOn`

Comment: Fixed that too, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index(where:)` method to find the index of your array element as follow:

```
struct Cur: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let symbol: String
    let switchVal: Bool
}

let cur1 = Cur(id: "a", name: "john", symbol: "j", switchVal: false)
let cur2 = Cur(id: "b", name: "steve", symbol: "s", switchVal: true)
let cur3 = Cur(id: "c", name: "Carl", symbol: "c", switchVal: false)

let list = [cur1, cur2, cur3]

if let index = list.index(where: {$0.switchVal}) {
    print(list[index]) // Cur(id: "b", name: "steve", symbol: "s", switchVal: true)\n"
    print(list[index].id)  // "b\n"
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am sure your code will work flawlessly and thank you for that. However, I am getting error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I am sure this has to do with my force-unwraps. Have to figure out those optionals. Thank you!